# Defining general type of functions

Tags: functions, c++

In Mathematica the term "function" refers to an expression that is evaluated given an input, and has a return value.

I was wondering if it's possible to define functions in the C++ sense, without using any external assistance.

Example of what I'm trying to do:
Say I want to write a function EvenOdd[x] defined as below:

```
      {
        If[ x \[Element] Integers, 
          If[GCD[x,2]==1, Print[x, " is an odd number"], Print[x , " is an even  
            number"] 
        ,Print[x , " is not an integer"]
                ]
       }
```

This function doesn't have a return value, rather it executes a code given an input (the functions I'm thinking about doesn't necessarily need an input) . While the example I gave can be easily worked around using normal functions, it wouldn't be good enough in general.

I feel like Mathematica should already have some kind of ability to do this, I'm just not sure what is the terminology used for this situation.

Answer (score 5):

There is a significant semantic argument as to whether what you're asking for is appropriately termed a "function". What you're requesting is, in C++ terms, a function of type `void`. However, overlooking that, it is perfectly possible to implement imperative subroutines of that sort in *Mathematica*. In fact your suggested code is essentially just lacking a name to call it by:

```
evenodd[x_] := (
  If[x \[Element] Integers,
    If[GCD[x, 2] == 1, Print[ToString[x] <> " is an odd integer."], 
      Print[ToString[x] <> " is an even integer."]],
  Print[ToString[x] <> " is not an integer."]];
  );

 evenodd[3]
```

> 3 is an odd integer.

Note the use of `:=` (`SetDelayed`) in the definition: that means that the code on the right hand side is evaluated in full every time the `evenodd[x_]` pattern appears, using the given `x`.

Similarly, imperative subroutines which take no arguments can be defined directly:

```
helloworld := Print["Hello world!"];
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @aalajmi You're welcome, though if you find yourself using that often in Mathematica, I would recommend considering whether Mathematica is the best language for your project. A lot of Mathematica's abilities come from its functions. It supports these paradigms, but it can't support them as intrinsically.